# Mover bigjar con maven y Spring boot

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

Cuando hago un desarrollo de un Big-jar con maven muevo el jar desde el directorio target a un directorio de pruebas mediante el siguiente segmento en el build:

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>../test</outputDirectory>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>cl.myapp.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Pero con Spring boot debo usar el siguiente plugin para empaquetar un big-jar

```
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

y en el plugin de boot no he encontrado algo similar a tag outputDirecory para mover el jar generado

¿Quizas con una tarea posterior en Ant podria mover el big-jar generado a mi directorio de pruebas?

Answer (score 1):

Encontre una solucion con un plugin que ejecuta tareas de ANT

```
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>


        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <tasks>
                            <copy file="target/myapp.jar" tofile="../test/myapp.jar" />
                        </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>


    </plugins>
```